# Correct way to account for MySQL session variables using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying out a [neat solution](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group) for getting top N rows per each group.  The solution makes use of two session variables `@country_rank` and `@current_country`.  The solution works well while directly working with the DB but it has issues with JDBC, perhaps because I am not passing the session variables correctly.

With JDBC the query is retrieving all entries, not just N entries per group.

Table definition and sample table entries are as follows:

```
   CREATE TABLE cities
   (
      city VARCHAR(80),
      country VARCHAR(80),
      population INT
   );
 
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('New York', 'United States', 8175133); 
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Los Angeles', 'United States', 3792621); 
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Chicago', 'United States', 2695598); 
 
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Paris', 'France', 2181000);
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Marseille', 'France', 808000);
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Lyon', 'France', 422000);
 
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('London', 'United Kingdom',   7825300);
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Birmingham', 'United Kingdom', 1016800);
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Leeds', 'United Kingdom', 770800);
```

The following query returns the top 2 cities for each country, by population:

```
SELECT city, country, population
   FROM
     (SELECT city, country, population, 
                  @country_rank := IF(@current_country = country, @country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,
                  @current_country := country 
       FROM cities
       ORDER BY country, population DESC
     ) ranked
   WHERE country_rank <= 2;
```

The database output is as follows:

```
+-------------+----------------+------------+
| city        | country        | population |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
| Paris       | France         |    2181000 |
| Marseille   | France         |     808000 |
| London      | United Kingdom |    7825300 |
| Birmingham  | United Kingdom |    1016800 |
| New York    | United States  |    8175133 |
| Los Angeles | United States  |    3792621 |
+-------------+----------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

My JDBC code is given below.  I tried various options to pass the session variables but nothing seems to work (in the sense that instead of getting Top 2 entries from each group, I am getting all the entries.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String dbURL;
    dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + domain + ":3306/" + DBNAME + "?sessionVariables=country_rank,current_country";
    // Option 1: Throws  java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable error
    
    dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + domain + ":3306/" + DBNAME + "?country_rank,current_country";
    // Option 2: Effectively a no-op
    
    dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + domain + ":3306/" + DBNAME + "?country_rank=null&current_country=null";
    // Option 3: Effectively a no-op
    
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUserName, dbPassword);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    
    String query = "SELECT city, country, population FROM ";
    query += "(SELECT city, country, population, ";
    query += "@country_rank := IF(@current_country = country, @country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,";
    query += "@current_country := country FROM cities ";
    query += "ORDER BY country, population DESC ";
    query += ") ranked WHERE country_rank <= 2";
    
    System.out.println("Query: " + query);
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    
    int count = 0;
    while(rs.next()) {
        String city = rs.getString(1);
        String country = rs.getString(2);
        Integer population = rs.getInt(3);
        
        System.out.println(++count + ": " + city + "|" + country + "|" + population);
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

The **wrong** JDBC program output is as follows:

```
1: Paris|France|2181000
2: Marseille|France|808000
3: Lyon|France|422000
4: London|United Kingdom|7825300
5: Birmingham|United Kingdom|1016800
6: Leeds|United Kingdom|770800
7: New York|United States|8175133
8: Los Angeles|United States|3792621
9: Chicago|United States|2695598
```

Comment: This is another place where it would be really helpful to upgrade your MariaDB to 10.2

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It fails the first time but then it works for the next executions.
Does anyone know why and how to fix it? thanks